# Add optional Sign up fee in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-community

Good Morning,

I'm trying to achieve the following: customers can choose While register for new account  between two options. First option is one in which fix amount of fee is added to access or subscribe for download section(category) .In the second option no fee or don't subscribe for download section.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution for this. Maybe you'll find an extension providing such a feature.

To get some help from the Magento community here, you will need to add some more details regarding your plan:

- Is this a one-time fee (only at sign-up) or is the fee added every time for the download section?
- What kind of fee is it: Fixed value or per cent?
- Does it apply per order/per item?
- ...

I guess it would be best to create this functionality on your own as it might be hard to find something that satisfies your needs ready to use. If you encounter any problems during development, come back to this platform with specific new questions and detailed information.